# R, Rscript, Works when variables hard coded, but not when passed as argument

Tags: r, command-line, arguments, rscript

I built the following R script to take a .csv generated by an automated report and split it into several .csv files.

This code works perfectly, and outputs a .csv file for each unique value of "facility" in "todays_data.csv":

```
disps <- read.csv("/Users/me/Downloads/todays_data.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")
for (facility in levels(disps$Facility)) {
temp <- subset(disps, disps$Facility == facility & disps$Alert.End == "")
temp <- temp[order(temp$Unit, temp$Area),]
fn <- paste("/Users/me/Documents/information/", facility, "_todays_data.csv", sep = "")
write.csv(temp, fn, row.names=FALSE)
}
```

But this does not output anything:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
file <- args[1]
disps <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep=",")
for (facility in levels(disps$Facility)) {
temp <- subset(disps, disps$Facility == facility & disps$Alert.End == "")
temp <- temp[order(temp$Unit, temp$Area),]
fn <- paste("/Users/me/Documents/information/", facility, "_todays_data.csv", sep = "")
write.csv(temp, fn, row.names=FALSE)
}
```

The only difference between the two files is that the first hardcodes the path to the .csv file to be split, while the second one has it passed as an argument in the command line using Rscript.

The read.csv() command works with the passed file path, because I can successfully run commands like head(disps) while running the script via Rscript.

Nothing within the for-loop will execute when run via Rscript, but things before and after it will.

Does anyone have any clues as to what I've missed? Thank you.

Comment: The subset function is dangerous (as described in its help page) and you have magnified that danger by using incorrectly. In interactive use this would be the correct code: `subset(disps, Facility == facility & Alert.End == "")`. My advice would be to use "[[" instead of subset when doing any sort of programming.

Comment: Well, why don't you take a look at what's actually in `file` to verify that it is a character string with the proper path?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I didn't include it, but I executed:

    head(disps)

within the Rscripts version, and got the values I expected. That's why I know the .csv path is being ported correctly.

Comment: Looking at your code and trusting what you say, the only possible reason I see is that you file must be missing a `Facility` column. Try to add `stopifnot("Facility" %in% names(disps))` before the loop and see what you get.

Comment: Also, are you sure that `Facility` is a factor? If it is coded as an integer or character, for instance, the levels will be `NULL`

Comment: Well, it couldn't be a character vector, since stringsAsFactors=TRUE by default but it could be a numeric or integer value. Perhaps trying `for( facility in unique(as.character(disps$Facility)) )`